# Remove two consecutive numbers from the list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting, arraylist

I have a list of integer numbers and I want to remove from this list the couples of consecutive numbers.

For example, from this list:

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100, 11, 12, 100, 14, 15, 100, 7, 8, 9, 100, 26, 27 }
```

I want to have this result:

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100, 100, 100, 7, 8, 9, 100 }
```

This is the executing code:

```
    var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100, 11, 12, 100, 14, 15, 100, 7, 8, 9, 100, 26, 27 };

    list.Add(-1);
    int counter = 0;
    bool nonecons = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if ((i + 1 < list.Count))
        {
            if ((list[i + 1] - list[i]) == 1)
            {
                counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                nonecons = true;
                if (counter < 2 && nonecons == true) 
                {
                    if (list[i] != 100)
                    {
                        list.Remove(list[i]);
                        list.Remove(list[i - 1]);
                    }

                    counter = 0;
                    nonecons = false;
                }
                else if (counter >= 2 && nonecons == true) 
                {
                    counter = 0;
                    nonecons = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
```

But when i run this code I have this unexpected result:

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100, 100, 100, 7, 100 }
```

What I need to change?

Comment: Why exactly two consecutive numbers to be removed? In your example  1, 2, 3, 4, 5 are five consecutive numbers. Removing two consecutive numbers from that in an iterative fashion would reduce 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 to the number 5. And it would reduce 7, 8, 9 to the number 9. Is that the desired outcome?

Comment: I need groups of 3 and more than 3 consecutive numbers @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace

Comment: Then please edit your question and don't make it sound like you want to remove pairs of consecutive numbers. Also, it would help if you could show the actual expected result for the input list `{ -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100, 100, 100, 7, 8, 9, 100 }` in your question(!) so it is unambiguously clear to us what you expect your code to do....

Comment: I want to delete groups of consecutive numbers that are less than 2, but my list will never have a single number. @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace

Comment: "_I want to delete groups of consecutive numbers that are less than 2_" So you want delete consecutive numbers but not 1, 2 (2 following directly after 1)? Or do i misunderstand?

Comment: but that group is 5 consecutive numbers, you say 1,2,3,4,5. I want to remove consecutive numbers less than 2. @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace , my question is pretty obvious why it got -2 points out of nowhere.

Comment: why did you delete your sentence, can u help me? just i need If there are 1 or 2 numbers in front of 100, I want to remove it, but if there are 3 numbers, nothing will happen. The search for groups of 2 will continue. @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace

Comment: Hmm, okay. Let's take a look at your code. First, the `nonecons == true` condition in your `if`/`else if` expressions will _always be true, because you do set _nonecons_ to true _right before the `if`/`else if`. So, that's one problem in the code.

Comment: so what should i do? @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace i didnt figure out

Comment: dude you again delete your comment ,i am reading it @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace

Comment: My bad, apologies, because i misread your code, and in the meantime i tested your code on dotnetfiddle, and what can i say, it doesn't produce what you seem to claim it produces: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oQEKta The result the code in your question produces is `1,2,3,4,5,100,100,100,7,100` and not ` 1,2,3,100,100,100,7,100 ` as your question seems to claim. So i am a bit at a loss. It's still missing the 8,9 you are expecting, though...

Comment: thank you, i edited my answer result, i missed that sorry for that. I'm trying other things, I couldn't figure it out yet, I'm having trouble. @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace

Comment: Why are the `100` items special-cased? Is it that you simply want to remove any items where there are two and only two consecutive numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the how you use an index value to iterate over the list and in which direction you iterate the indexer: "upwards" the list towards the end, combined with how/where you remove elements from the list.

Imagine a list with the elements `100,14,15,100,100,7,8,9,100` (to take a snippet from your example list). Your code is processing this and is at index position being 3, pointing at the element `100` after element `15`, when we start looking at what the code is doing:

```
100, 14, 15,100,100,  7,  8,  9,100
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
             ^
             i=3
```

Your code correctly detected that `14,15` is a consecutive sequence of a length smaller than 3, and proceeds to remove them.

Now the list looks like `100,100,100,7,8,9,100`. So far so good.

But, and herein lies the problem, the current index position value hasn't changed. It's still 3. And then comes the next iteration step, with the index position now being 4. So, the next element considered by your code after deleting `14,15` is the element `8`:

```
100,100,100,  7,  8,  9,100
--- --- --- --- --- --- ---
                 ^
                 i=4
```

Because the element positions/indices have shifted to the left due to the removal of prior elements, but the index position hold in the `i` variable has not been adjusted to account for this shift, the code **misses the `100` element in front of the `7` element and the `7` element itself.**

This leads your code to detect only the consecutive sequence `8,9` instead of `7,8,9` (due to it skipping over the `7`), hence it proceeds deleting `8,9`.

The solution to your problem should now be clear: Whenever deleting elements in front of or at the index position held by `i`, you'll need to adjust the value of `i` to follow the left-shift of the elements after the removed elements.

This is done by decreasing the value of `i` by the amount of elements deleted in front or at the `i` position:

```
list.Remove(list[i]);
list.Remove(list[i - 1]);

i -= 2;
```

(As an alternative solution, the direction of iterating over the list could be switched to go "downwards" from the end towards the beginning of the list. Then any elements subject to removal would be *behind* the index position hold by `i`. And since `i` is only decreasing in this approach, the value in `i` wouldn't need to be adjusted because any elements still to be iterated over wouldn't have their position shifted. However, this would require significantly more changes to your code and isn't done with adding a single code line like `i -= 2;`)

---

(There are other concerns to be found with your code, like the not very useful *nonecons* variable that has not discernible effect, but it's unrelated to the problem with the incorrect result, so it's not really an issue...)

Comment: heyyyyyyyyy dude you are brilliant ? am i wrong

Comment: you changed everything all of a sudden, I had no hope.

Comment: @blacksunday "_am i wrong_" yes you are. As you are already aware, i can be a bit scatterbrained sometimes. Brilliant people are not scatterbrained. Mad scientists, on the other hand... ;-P